# make my node-red flow only run my node-red

Tags: node.js, encryption, node-red

I'm going to encrypt my node-red flow in case others export my node-red flow and import it into a node-red that is not deployed by me. In other words, I want to make my exported flow can only run on my node-red.

I've try to read the source of node-red projet, but I didn't find any code or api about exporting flow or importing flow. I want to know where they are to add my code. Or are there any other solutions to make my need?

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here, why not just either limit access to the editor but adding authentication or disable the editor completely? Also anybody with access to the machine the instance is running on will have access to the flow file

Comment: I just want to customize a nodered that only allows the exported files to run on it. Because we need to teach our clients how to use Nodered, they can write their desired features on it and also maintain the features we implement, but we need to prevent them from exporting our own features for other purposes. So I have to add a function to encrypt the flow before export it as a file. If they send the file to others who didn't  use our customized node-red, it can't work. I want to know where are  exporting  and importing  in the nodered source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The export function is in the editor code (frontend)

The function that shows the export dialogue is here:

https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/9bd71319143a26f654810d0d05ccc08c7603a95d/packages/node_modules/%40node-red/editor-client/src/js/ui/clipboard.js#L565